# Google Insert Events Duplicating In Google Calendar By Clicking Insert Button again and again

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have used a button for inserting events but when i click button again it inserts again and created a duplicate copies of events. Is there any way to only insert latest events.

{

```
      var request;

      for (var j = 0; j < this.state.syncEvent.length; j++) {

        console.log("J loop", this.state.syncEvent[j]);

        request = function (resource) {

          return gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({

            'calendarId': 'primary',

            'eventId': resource

          });

        }(this.state.syncEvent[j]);

        request.execute(function (resp: any) {

          console.log(resp);

        });

      }

    }
```

Comment: your going to have to check the calendar to see if the event has already been inserted otherwise your code is just going to do what you tell it to do which is create new events.

Answer (score 1):

### If you are inserting an event with a predefined event id - check first if an event with this id already exists

First of all, there are some problems with your code.

Have a look at the Javasript sample in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples):

The correct syntax would be:

```js
var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
  'calendarId': 'primary',
  'resource': event
});
```

whereby `event` is the event resource of type

```js
var event = {
  ...
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'id': SPECIFY_HERE_THE_EVENT_ID,
  ... 
};
```

The event resource must contain the `Required Properties` `end` and `start`, in addition you specify additional properties mentioned in the documentaiton of the method  like e.g.  `summary` or `id`.

Now, since from your code snippet one can deduct that you pass the event id to your function  - before inserting the event, you can check with the method [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) either an event with the given id already exists.

Alternatively, you can also use the method [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) to retrieve the already existing events in your calendar. Thereby you can use the query parameter `q` to filter by e.g. `summary` or you can query by specifying the paramters `timeMax` and `timeMin` - depending on your use case.

All you need to do is to implement a conditional statement to create a new event only if `Events: get` or `Events: list` did not return an already existing event with the specified parameters.

Comment: when using id i am getting error :
{code: 400, data: Array(1), message: "Invalid resource id value.", error: {…}}
code: 400
data: Array(1)
0:
domain: "global"
message: "Invalid resource id value."
reason: "invalid"

Comment: What does your id look like? Is it unique?

Comment: Hi Zig, my events from fullcalendar plugin are getting added to google calendar thanks. Only events:list part condition remaining, it doesnt have documentation for javascript.

Comment: Glad the event creation works now. As for `events:list`: Go to the documentation of the method and expand the `Try this API` window: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list?apix=true. You can specify the parameters as desired and then choose on the right the `cURL`, `HTTP` or `JAVASCRIPT` tab to see the respective code implementation.

Comment: when i am using events: list i am getting all events in calendar with their unique id's but the problem is duplicate events also have unique ids so how will i know who is existing?

Comment: It depends on how you define an event as a dublicate. For example if the same `summary`, `timeMax` and `timeMin` make the vent  a dublicate - that you should specify those parameters when listing existing events.